# JSF, Primefaces LazyDataModel - update row without invoking load method

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a simple lazy data model with 2 columns. The second column has only checkboxes which are disabled by default (cannot click them). On row select I want only enable the checkbox (checkbox.disabled = false) without invoking `load` method - because my data is not changed so there is no need to request database. The problem is that when I update my dataTable to change checkbox.disabled to `false`, then RENDER_PHASE is invoked and `load` method gets called, on other hands if I don't update my data table, then the checkbox is always disabled. How can I make it work together?

UPDATE:

```
<h:form id="form-id">
            <p:dataTable var="element"
                         id="data-table-id"
                         value="#{view.elements}"
                         lazy="true"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                         selectionMode="single"
                         rows="5"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,30"
                         selection="#{view.selectedElement}">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                        listener="#{view.someMethod()}"
                        update="checkbox"/>

                <p:column headerText="Element"
                          width="300">
                    <h:outputText value="#{element.name}"/>
                </p:column>


                <p:column headerText="Active"
                          width="300">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox"
                            disabled="#{view.selectedElement.id ne element.id}"
                            value="#{element.active}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

When I put `update="form-id"` then active checkbox gets enabled - but as I said, the `load` method is invoked what is undesirable behavior

Comment: What about not update whole datatable, but checkbox only?

Comment: Because `load` method is invoked when I update whole table :/

Comment: That why I said you don't need to update datatable. Simple update checkbox.

Comment: I added code to question, can you check if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just the way JSF works if you say update="form-id" JSF will rerender the entire form including rebuilding your datatable which thus calls your load method.

What it sounds like you want is to update a single row check out [OmniFaces Ajax.updateRow](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax) method.

So for example JSF...

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{myDataTable}"

<p:commandButton value="Update" action="#{ajaxBean.updateRow(myDataTable, 0)}" />
```

Java:

```
public void updateRow(UIData table, int index) {
   Ajax.updateRow(table, index);
}
```

Comment: Yup, I had to update just particular row and it worked :]